# What is the difference between Rune Classic and Rune Gold [GOG]

Tags: version-differences, rune-classic

I acquired Rune from GOG, I installed the classic and gold version, but I see no difference. Is it more worth to play gold or I should stay with classic version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rune Gold includes the multiplayer-only expansion, Halls of Valhalla. It comes with 33 maps and 2 new multiplayer game modes.

Therefore it does not make any difference which version you play, if you play singleplayer only.

Comment: Rune Classic lacks some levels, which were - for some reason - cut out.